# if statement nested in while loop, but it didnt work

Tags: bash

I was working on a loop question. It asked to create an if statement inside while loop, and it should loop while `greeting_occasion` is less than 3. If I run the script, it should say `Nice to meet you!` followed by two `How are you?`

I wrote in this way (below) first and it didn't work. I later changed the `greeting_occasion=$((greeting_occasion +1))` to outside the if statement, then it works. But I don't understand why my code didn't work at the first time.

```
first_greeting="Nice to meet you!"
later_greeting="How are you?"
greeting_occasion=0
while [ $greeting_occasion -lt 3 ]
do
if [ $greeting_occasion -lt 1 ]
then
  echo $first_greeting
  greeting_occasion=$((greeting_occasion +1))
else
  echo $later_greeting
  greeting_occasion=$((greeting_occasion +1))
fi
done
```

Comment: It works. The way you expected. It prints `Nice to meet you!` then it prints two lines of `How are you?`.

Comment: ***How*** doesn't it work? What happens when you run your script? What is supposed to happen? Please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Note that you can extract the increment outside the `if` as it happens in the both branches.

Comment: Yeah, it's working in both cases with increment inside if-else or outside.

Comment: variable inside sinigle braket should be double quoted to avoid argument splitting or in case variable is not defined